# Comprobar si existe un archivo en Laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy haciendo un proyecto en Laravel y me necesito que cuando no encuentre una imagen almacene en la base de datos que no existe la imagen, pero no sé qué condición debería poner en el if:

```php
$ruta_img = 'src/Productos/BG-'.$resultado['RefFabrica'].'.jpg';
$resultado['rutaimg']=asset(Storage::url($ruta_img ?: 'src/Productos/default.jpg' ));

if() {
 // Encuentra la imagen
}
else {
 // no ecuentra la imagen 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así:

```
if (file_exists($ruta_img)){
    //existe
}
```

Sin embargo, veo que estás usando el Storage Facade, por lo que esta otra alternativa es más apropiada:

```
$existe = Storage::exists($ruta_img);

if (file_exists($existe)){
    //existe
}
```